# Using the Ocean Browsercaps files with .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, browsercaps

I have been trying to use the Ocean browsercaps files from http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/ in a ASP.NET 4 application. When I drop the files into the App_Browsers folder I get the error

**The browser or gateway element with ID 'docomon505i' cannot be found.**

Are these files compatible with .NET4 or am I doing something wrong. The documentation is sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not released new version that will work with .Net4. I am in the process of building and testing the new browser definition files as we speak. But I am not ready to release them.

Owen.

Comment: Thanks Owen. I did hack around a bit and get the old versions to work but will wait for the official versions.

Comment: Thank you for your great work, Owen. I got an error when using OceanSpiders.v4.browser: couldn't find element netscape3 at line <browser id="netscape3spider" parentID="netscape3">. Do you have up-to-date files for .NET4?